# PHP and javascript combination to bring up a dynamic modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

So here's the thing. I have a database where i echo all images from a table.
Here is the code of my 'gallery.php' file:

```
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="row">
    <?php
        require('dbparams.php');
        try{
            $pdoObject = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost; dbname=$dbname;",$dbuser, $dbpass);
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM pictures";
            $statement = $pdoObject -> prepare($sql);
            $result = $statement -> execute();
            while($record=$statement->fetch()){
                $filename = $record['filename'];
                $mimetype = $record['mimetype'];
                $filedata = $record['filedata'];
                $id=$record['id'];
                echo "<div class='col-sm-5 col-md-3'>";
                    echo "<div class='thumbnail'>";
                        echo "<a id='p' href='#imagemodal'><img id='imageresource' src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($filedata)."' alt='Click'></a>";
                        echo "<div class='caption'>";
                            echo "<h3>Thumbnail label</h3>";
                            echo "<p>...</p>";
                        echo "</div>";
                    echo "</div>";
                echo "</div>";
                }       
            $statement->closeCursor();
            $pdoObject = null;
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            header('Location: index.php?msg=PDO Exception: '.$e->getMessage());
            exit();
        }
        ?></div>
</div>
```

Everything works just fine and here is the code for my modal (bootstrap). It is on an external PHP file and i use the require 'imagemodal.php'; :

```
<?php
echo '<div class="modal fade" id="imagemodal" role="dialog">';
echo '<div style="width:85%;" class="modal-dialog">';
    echo '<div class="modal-content">';
        echo '<div class="modal-header">';
            echo '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>';
            echo '<h4 class="modal-title"></h4>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div id="mainmod" class="modal-body">';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="modal-footer">';
            echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>';
        echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
?>
```

In the 'gallery.php' file i thought i could use javascript-jquery so for every call through the "a" tag i would create an "img" tag with the specific one image that called the js code. The problem is that while it works just fine, whenever i click on an image and whatever that image is, it echoes the 1st image from gallery.For example , lets say i have 10 images. All code works fine. But if i click on 1st image , 2nd image , 3rd image it always opens the modal with the 1st. What could i possibly do wrong? Here is the js code in the gallery.php file :

```
<script>
        $("[id='p']").click(function() {
            $("#mainmod").empty();
            $("#mainmod").append("<img id='imagepreview' src=''>")
            $("[id='imagepreview']").attr('src', $("[id='imageresource']").attr('src'));
            $("[id='imagemodal']").modal('show');
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: You can pass an image URL to the modal

Comment: echo '<div class="modal fade" id="imagemodal" role="dialog">';
The ID of each model should be unique, otherwise it will always open the same.

Comment: Your modal has a id, in your case imagemodal. Youre refereing to in with "href='#imagemodal" So when you take a look at how your code looks when you have more than one modal on a side, they have all the ID of imagemodal. So the href=imagemodal will always open the first element with that ID. So if you have for example 5 images you have 5 times id=imagemodel", but it should be something like imagemodel1, imagemodel2, imagemodel3 etc. Then it won't always open the first one ;)

Comment: Your jQuery says `[id='p']`. Instead, write`p` for selecting a paragraph element or`#p` for selecting an element with id `p`

Comment: @Twinfriends Tottaly got it.But how could i accomplish that? I thought that i could wrap my js code in a function where it gets the id from "a" href..so i would create the modal for each unique picture.Am i right ?

Comment: A few month ago i ran into the same issue as you. I resolved the problem by taking the filename as ID for the modal. When you're sure the filename is unique, there's no problem with it.

Comment: @k97513 The way i have it brings up the modal anyway but only with the 1st picure. The way you say brings up the modal ONLY with the first picture. With the rest of them no modal no image.

Answer (score 0):

Sidenote: Ids in HTML should be unique.

You select the src from the first item with id "imageresource" that is found in the whole document. What you want to do is select the src from the first img tag that is a child of the link the user just clicked.

```
echo "<a class='trigger' href='#imagemodal'><img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($filedata)."' alt='Click'></a>";
                    echo "<div class='caption'>";



<script>
        $(".trigger").click(function() {
            $("#mainmod").empty();
            $("#mainmod").append("<img id='imagepreview' src=''>")
            $("[id='imagepreview']").attr('src', this.children('img').attr('src'));
            $("[id='imagemodal']").modal('show');
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to clear the bootstrap modal on hide, try this

```
<script>
//reset the modal content
    $('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
        $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    });
</script>
```